# I can't seem to get Smoothing by Loop Cutting very well

Tags: modeling

I was making a bridge but while smoothing with loop cuts, I just cant add loop cuts (on the blue part). I tried inverting the normal behind the faces(in the second pic) but it didnt solve it. I also tried to delete the faces and do them manually but i still cant add loop cuts and also increases the amount of loopcuts needed.
*Note: Note sure if that's needed, but i have a mirror mod on too.
[image: Subsurf On]

[image: The Face i'm talking about is the one above the selected one...i cant add a loop cut there...]

It's the first project im trying by myself(out of my own imagination), so i dont want to be discouraged...

Comment: Loop Cuts will only work properly with quad based topology and as far I can see there is and ngon which is preventing placing Loop Cut.

Comment: Yep! Thx i fixed it using triangular faces instead...

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind i fixed it by deleting the face and used triangular faces instead. This let me add the loop cuts.
[image]

Comment: You could lower amount of faces and improve the edge flow by dissolving 2 diagonal edges which form the tris and connecting the edge loops from the bottom either with Knife or Connect Vertex Path tools